# How do you publish a JMS topic with Spring JMS?

Tags: java, spring, jms

I have a component that sends messages to a queue to be handled by another system. It should also publish a topic about job statuses every once in a while. Can I just use the same JmsTemplate used to send to a queue AND to publish to a topic?

I created a new topic in ActiveMQ, except that when I send from JmsTemplate a message, a new queue with the topic name gets created with the sent message (instead of sending the data to the actual topic), what am I doing wrong here?

here's my config:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="jmsExceptionListener" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100" />
</bean>

<!--  JmsTemplate Definition -->
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="messageFacade" class="org.foo.MessageFacadeJms">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
</bean>
```

MessageFacadeJms is the class I use to send a queue message (and it works), can I also just used that to publish a topic?

Can I just use this to do both queue sending and topic publishing?:

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("TOPIC_NAME" /* or queue name */, message);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This might seem a bit odd, you need to tell JmsTemplate that it's a topic rather than a queue, by setting its `pubSubDomain` property to `true`.

That means you're going to need two `JmsTemplate` beans, one for the queue, and one for the topic:

```
<bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
   <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
   <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTopicTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
   <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
   <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 8):

If it's ok for you to use a naming convention for queue/topics, then you can implement a custom `org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DestinationResolver`

```
public class NamingDestinationResolver implements DestinationResolver {
   public Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName, boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
      if (destinationName.endsWith("Queue")) {
         return session.createQueue(destinationName);
      } else if (destinationName.endsWith("Topic")) {
         return session.createTopic(destinationName);
      }
      throw new RuntimeException("Naming convention not respected for destination " + destinationName);
   }
}
```

and reference it using `JmsTemplate.setDestinationResolver`

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. If you add @Component to the DestinationResolver, you don't even need to set it on JmsTemplate

Comment: @danielnovy if you found the answer useful, a vote up would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 7):

If you create the destination as a spring bean rather than using the destination name in your code, Spring won't need to know whether it is a topic or a queue. Else the solution suggested above should work as well.

AMQ JMS destinations can be created by directly instantiating them:

```
  <bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="TOPIC_NAME" />
  </bean>
```

or fetching from JNDI:

```
<bean id="topic" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="TOPIC_NAME"/>
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jmsJndiTemplate"/> 
</bean>
```

I prefer the JNDI technique as it is more standard.